# Menu lateral fijo, que no se mueva al hacer scroll (bajar)

Tags: html, css, position

Vi una publicación con negativos que le ocurría a un usuario que no podía hacer un menú lateral fijo a la izquierda y se la eliminaron pero yo entendí su código.

Si lo ves o para los futuros usuarios que tengan problemas con los menús fijos laterales, dejo un código bien sencillo de base que puede servir para empezar a hacer un menú lateral, y si lo retocas un `footer` o `navbar top`. Este hace uso de `position: fixed;`

Con esto se consigue tener un menú lateral el cual se quedará fijo todo el rato a la izquierda. En este caso, aunque bajes hacia abajo el menú seguirá en el mismo sitio. Esto se puede ver en la página web de *Youtube*.

Comment: Con aceptar tu propia respuesta, en un rato, basta para indicar que tiene solución. 

Ahora bien, la pregunta como está es bastante floja y pocos van a llegar a esa respuesta a partir de la pregunta. Trata de ponerle un poquito más de detalle

Comment: Intente dejarla asi un poco menos floja, no sabria como dejarla mejor para los demas usuarios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es básico, se podría mejorar y/o hacer `responsive`.
Espero que pueda ayudar esta aportación.

Dato: `1em` = `16px` de normal. Puede variar en ciertos casos. si para un selector CSS hemos especificado un `font-size` de `16px`, entonces `1em` = `16px`

```css
.menuLateral {
  height: 100%;
  width: fit-content;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: black;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding: 2em 1.5em 0em 0em; 
}

.menuLateral a {
  padding: 0.5em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: grey;
  display: block;
}

.menuLateral a:hover {
  color: white;
}


main {
  margin-left: 4em; /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 0em 1em;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

<div class="menuLateral">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#enlace1">Inicio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#enlace2">Contacto</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#enlace3">FAQ</a> </li>
   </ul>
</div>

<main>
  <h2>Menu lateral</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam gravida mauris id nunc laoreet, vel semper quam interdum. Etiam congue nibh id rutrum fringilla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nulla pellentesque mauris ante, at condimentum lacus finibus a. Nullam vitae suscipit turpis. Donec nec vehicula quam, nec malesuada diam. Pellentesque eget dolor volutpat, tristique justo vel, fermentum augue. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae;</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam gravida mauris id nunc laoreet, vel semper quam interdum. Etiam congue nibh id rutrum fringilla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nulla pellentesque mauris ante, at condimentum lacus finibus a. Nullam vitae suscipit turpis. Donec nec vehicula quam, nec malesuada diam. Pellentesque eget dolor volutpat, tristique justo vel, fermentum augue. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae;</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam gravida mauris id nunc laoreet, vel semper quam interdum. Etiam congue nibh id rutrum fringilla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nulla pellentesque mauris ante, at condimentum lacus finibus a. Nullam vitae suscipit turpis. Donec nec vehicula quam, nec malesuada diam. Pellentesque eget dolor volutpat, tristique justo vel, fermentum augue. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae;</p>

</main>
   
</body>
</html>
```